# Can I use Response.Redirect without encoding?

Tags: c#, response.redirect

I want to achieve that a file that is described by URL or network drive `(N:\ESSBP1-Office\Imagenes\Check list.xlsx)` can be opened through a browser by using the `resonse.redirect` function in c#. 
**BUT:** This only works for me if the path doesn't contain a space.

How can I avoid the encoding? If I type that same path into the InternetExplorer the address - with space - is resolved correctly and the file is opened.

Comment: look into using Server.UrlEncode()? -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.urlencode

Comment: U could always give the path to the browser and then some javascript to do the redirect

Comment: file:// (possibly file:///) instead of N:\, forward slashes throughout and %20 in place of any spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to avoid the encoding with the `response.redirect` function. `Server.UrlEncode()` didn't do that neither, as it just adds another unwanted encoding, while I wanted the exact content of a TextBox/Label to be the string passed to the browser's URL-bar, followed by hitting the enter key - which should be done through code.

I finally achieved that, following @Richard Housham´s suggestion using Javascript:

Mark-up:

```
<asp:TextBox id="TB_ExternalLink" runat="server"/>
<asp:LINKButton ID="LB_Open" runat="server" OnClick="OpenLink">Open Link</asp:LINKButton>
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hiddenExternalFile"/>
```

Code:

```
protected void OpenLink(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = TB_ExternalLink.Text.Replace(@"\\", @"\\");
    hiddenExternalFile.Value = url;
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "windowOpen()", true);
}
```

Javascript:

```
function windowOpen() { 
        Window = window.open(document.getElementById('hiddenExternalFile').value, "_blank"); 
}
```

Opens any link that is typed into the textbox in these formats in a new tab:

```
http://www.url.com
\\corp.root.int\INT-Host$\USR03\XXX\W10\Desktop\Kaizen MRO\RMA_Part.png
N:\ESSBP1-Office\Imagenes\Check list.xlsx
```

regardless of spaces or special ASCI characters